# Automated Transactional Emails Not Sending v 1.9.2.4

Tags: transactional-mail, magento1.9.2.4

I have upgraded to Magento v1.9.2.4 and my automated transactional emails do not get sent.

I have ensured that the transactional emails are enabled in system/configuration/sales_emails ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears these were being sent, but most were going in to customer spam folders. Needed to ensure server was configured to minimise the risk of these by following the suggestions on this page https://blog.amasty.com/5-steps-for-no-spam-e-mails-in-magento/